# Find pair of numbers inside an array is it possible to solve with bitwise operators

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Is it possible to solve this problem with bitwise operators?
Given an array of integers, find two same numbers and return one of them, for example in array [7,3,5,6,7] answer is 7. I'm trying to understand when a problem can be solved with bitwise. So far I understand that if I multiply or divide by 2 I would want to use a left shift to multiply by 2, right shift to divide by 2 and if I want to cancel out matching numbers use XOR. I was thinking I could exit a loop on the first matching pair but I now don't think I can. I've tried this.

```
function findIt(arr) {
  var dog = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if ((dog ^= arr[i]) == 0) {
      dog =arr[i];
      break;
    }
  }
  return dog;
}
```

It's not homework, i'm just curiously learning about bitwise operations in javascript. Below solved vanilla solution.

```js
function findIt(arr) {
  var obj = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (obj[arr[i]] === 1) {
      return arr[i];
    } else {
      obj[arr[i]] = 1;
    }
  }
  return 'no pairs found'
}

console.log(findIt([7,3,5,6,7))
```

Comment: Your function will only find equal numbers if they're next to each other. Is that what you want?

Comment: @barmar no, I wanted it to search for a number pair through the whole array and not if the numbers were next to each other. Find the only pair throughout the entire array. I'll change my example input.

Comment: Then you need to use nested loops, so you compare every element with every other element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Barmar already suggested in comments you can use nested for loops for solving the problem.

Something like this should do:

```
function findIt(arr) {
  var cmpValue, flag = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    cmpValue = arr[i];
    for(var j = i + 1 ; j < arr.length ; j++){
        if(cmpValue^arr[i] == 0){
            flag=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag == 1){
        break;
    }
  }
  if(flag == 1){
    return cmpValue;
  }
  else{
    return 'no pairs found'
  }

}

console.log(findIt([7,3,5,6,7))
> 7
console.log(findIt([3,3,5,6,7))
> 3
```